# Syncing across nested ParallelFor loops

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I have a class with a method that is running a nested `ParallelFor` loop.  Basically I'm iterating over a list of objects and then a list contained in the properties of each object.

Based on a condition that is calculated for each object in the inner loop, I want to add to a queue.  I'm using a "syncRoot" object in an attempt to maintain concurrency when adding to the queue.

```
public class ParallelTest
{
    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    public void Test() {
       List<MyLog> queue = new List<MyLog>();
       ...
       Parallel.For(0, set.Count(), delegate(int i)
       {
           var obj = set[i];
           List<Connection> conns = obj.GetConnections();
           ...      
           Parallel.For(0, conns.Count(), delegate(int j)
           {    
               Connection c = conns[j];
               MyLog log = new MyLog();             
               ...                  
               if (condition)
               {                    
                   lock (syncRoot)
                   {
                       queue.Add(log);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       Debug.WriteLine(queue.Count);
   }
}
```

The problem I have is that it seems not all of my objects are getting added to the queue.  I'm testing for a set of 200 objects and replacing the `condition` with `true`, so I would expect `queue.Count` to be 200.  However, I get strange results ... sometimes 200, sometimes 198 or 199.

What am I doing wrong here?  How do I ensure each thread is accounted for?

Comment: That's quite a broad locking strategy for a local variable. You could declare `syncLock` in the same scope as `queue` if that's all you're using it for. Better still, seeing as ordering is not guaranteed anyway, why not use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` and get rid of locking altogether?

Comment: Tried `ConcurrentBag<T>`. Same behavior.  200 in first test, 199 in second.

Comment: I might be losing my mind, but I take back my previous comment.  This seems to be working now. I'll test it into the ground and see if I can break it, but this might be the solution I need.

Comment: If you can move away from explicit loops and explicit locking, you'll definitely be less susceptible to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an excellent candidate for Linq.

Assuming the code represented by `...` could be encapsulated in a method with signature:

```
void Initialize(MyLog log, Connection conn, SomeUnknownType obj)
```

Your code could reduce to the following linq statement:

```
    var logs = set  
        .AsParallel()
        .SelectMany(
            obj =>
                obj.GetConnections()
                    .Select(conn => new{obj, conn}))
        .Select(x => { 
            var o = new{x.obj, x.conn, log = new MyLog()};
            Initialize(o.log, o.conn, o.obj); //or just do work inline
            return o;
        })
        .Where(x => x.obj... && x.conn...) //someCondition

    queue = logs.ToList();
```

Seeing as `set.Count()` is relatively high, parallelizing over `set` will ensure that the work is reasonably well divided over available cores. There's no need to parallelize again later on.

Comment: Part of the "..." after each log is created is some processing that takes a variable (and potentially long) amount of time, so the Parallel is important.

Comment: Unknown.  I'm volume testing with 200-300, thinking that would be a high amount.  But it will depend.

Comment: @Paul Hopefully the changes to my answer are good for your needs. They will ensure that the additional work is parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConcurrentQueue<T> Class` instead `List<T>` . See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

for more information.